# Why one way works and other doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
if(chk) {
        document.getElementById(messagebox).innerHTML="update do be done";
        document.getElementById(messagebox).style.color="green"; 

        } else {
            document.getElementById(messagebox).innerHTML="no update";
        document.getElementById(messagebox).style.color="red"; 
        };  
});
```

chk is a variable that comes from here:

```
var chk = ((lenta >= 1) && (lenta <= 5) && (str.search(/[0-9¬!\"£\$%^\&\*\(\)_\-+\=\{\}\[\]#~@\';\:\/\?>\.<\,\\\ |]/) <= -1));
```

basically, if chk is true, it means that input is correct.
In this case, input allows only letters and lenght between 1 and 5.

script works fine but, if instead of "

```
document.getElementById(messagebox).innerHTML="update do be done";
        document.getElementById(messagebox).style.color="green";
```

" I add
"

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',  
        data: ({quoteprefix : str}),
        url: 'liveupdate/firstsetup.php',
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById(messagebox).innerHTML=" <?php echo pw('updatedone'); ?>. "+data+"";
            document.getElementById(messagebox).style.color="green";
        } 
    });
"
```

script updates no matter the inputted value
Example: if I input AB it updates AB.
If I input AB123 it updates "AB"

the full script is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var ffind = "#quoteprefix"; //input value id
$(ffind).on("change paste keyup", function() {
    var messagebox = "qquoteprefix"; //message box
    var lenta = $(this).val().length;
    var str = $(this).val();

    var chk = ((lenta >= 1) && (lenta <= 5) && (str.search(/[0-9¬!\"£\$%^\&\*\(\)_\-+\=\{\}\[\]#~@\';\:\/\?>\.<\,\\\ |]/) <= -1));
    
    if (chk) {
        $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
        $(this).addClass("is-valid");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("is-valid");
        $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
    };
    


}); 

$(ffind).on("focusout", function() {
    
if(chk) {
        document.getElementById(messagebox).innerHTML="update de facut";
        document.getElementById(messagebox).style.color="green"; 

        } else {
            document.getElementById(messagebox).innerHTML="nu face update" +chk;
        document.getElementById(messagebox).style.color="red"; 
        };  
});




});
```

UPDATE:
tried this, same result:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var ffind = "#quoteprefix"; 
$(ffind).on("change paste keyup", function() {
    var messagebox = "qquoteprefix";
    var lenta = $(this).val().length;
    var str = $(this).val();
    var chk=false;
    var chk = ((lenta >= 1) && (lenta <= 5) && (str.search(/[0-9¬!\"£\$%^\&\*\(\)_\-+\=\{\}\[\]#~@\';\:\/\?>\.<\,\\\ |]/) <= -1));
    
    if (chk) {
        $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
        $(this).addClass("is-valid");

        $(this).focusout( function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                data: ({quoteprefix : $(this).val()}),
                url: 'liveupdate/firstsetup.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById(messagebox).innerHTML=" <?php echo pw('updatedone'); ?>."+chk;
                    document.getElementById(messagebox).style.color="green";
                } 
            });
        });

    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("is-valid");
        $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
    };
    

}); 


});
```

Why?
Can someone help me

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: tried to put focusout function inside of change, paste, keyup..

Comment: Did you really mean to use `str.search(...) <= -1`? There is no reason for it to be less than -1. To me it seems you meant to use `>=`.

Comment: Plus there is no point of putting PHP code directly in your HTML withou it getting executed by the server first.

Comment: wais, str.search(...) must not contain those chars.

Comment: wais, what do you mean by "no point of putting PHP code directly in your HTML withou it getting executed by the server? the php code calles just some variables and functions. it works.

Comment: Trying more options, I have realised that at "onfocusout" event doesn't takes the chk value. it consider it as being "true". for "focusout" event I need to do all checks again.

Answer (score 0):

So, I find this working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var ffind = "#<?php echo $field; ?>"; 
var messagebox = "<?php echo $field[0].$field; ?>";
$(ffind).on("change paste keyup", function() {
    var notallowedchars = /[0-9¬!\"£\$%^\&\*\(\)_\-+\=\{\}\[\]#~@\';\:\/\?>\.<\,\\\ |]/;
    
    var chk = (($(this).val().length >= 1) && 
              ($(this).val().length <= 5) && 
              ($(this).val().search(notallowedchars) <= -1));
    
    if (chk) {
        $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
        $(this).addClass("is-valid");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("is-valid");
        $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
    };
    
$(this).focusout( function() {
    var chk = (($(this).val().length >= 1) && 
              ($(this).val().length <= 5) && 
              ($(this).val().search(notallowedchars) <= -1));
    if (chk) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                data: ({quoteprefix : $(this).val()}),
                url: 'liveupdate/firstsetup.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById(messagebox).innerHTML=" <?php echo pw('updatedone'); ?>.";
                    document.getElementById(messagebox).style.color="green";
                } 
            });
    } else {
        document.getElementById(messagebox).innerHTML="<?php echo pw('noupdatedone'); ?>";
        document.getElementById(messagebox).style.color="red";
    }
}); 

}); 

});
```

Apparently at "focusout" function I need to do all checks once again.